# Emails with Attachments

Tags: grammar

I'm wondering what is the best way to express that an email contains more than one attachment. Would saying "Please find the attached (name of document). Our (name of document) is also attached." be proper?

Answer (score 7):

Or you could simply, and more to the point, just say

> See attachments.

Comment: Alternatively, "See attached."

Answer (score 3):

Or...

> ***Please find attached the following documents:***
>
> - ***Document 1 name***
> - ***Document 2 name, etc.***

As a note of interest - the ***"Please find attached..."*** sounds funny to me now but ***way*** back in my clerical admin days, it was perfectly correct and acceptable.

Comment: +1. Best way in my opinion. I have done this way lot of times. It reduces any ambiguity from receiver's mind. Adding to this, more information could also be added in front of document-names to illustrate their purpose more.

Answer (score 2):

If you refer to the attachments in the body of the email, you could say that they are attached at the point where you mention them with something like '. . . and, as you will see, I'm sending them as attachments to this email.'

Comment: Can't we use "enclosed" here or it's irrelevant?

Comment: @Benyamin Hamidekhoo. No, _enclosed_ isn't appropriate in the context of electronic communication. You have to enclose something in something else, such as an envelope.

Comment: @BenyaminHamidekhoo Unless you were actually *enclosing* the document itself within the body of the email. If you copied and pasted a section into your email you could say, please see the *enclosed* because it would be enclosed in the email. If you were *attaching* the document to the email, enclosed wouldn't not be appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

How about "Please see the attached documents" and then if you feel the need to name each one you can simply list.

Ex. "Please see the attached documents: item 1, item 2 etc." (Check the correct punctuation for using lists however, ex. : or ; or ,)